# Getting not authorized error in Eclipse while trying to clone a Git repository using GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, git-clone, github-for-windows

[image]

I have created a Java project in my Eclipse and I want to upload that to GitHub. I created a new repository in GitHub. I copied the repository URL and, using *Clone Git Repository*, I tried to upload my Java project. I have entered the URL and provided login credentials of GitHub. After entering credentials, I am getting error dialog. (See the image which is attached.). Can please someone help me on this?

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem, but from the image you posted, it appears that you are using a **very** old version of Eclipse. Maybe you should consider upgrading to the latest version? At time of writing this comment, latest Eclipse version is 2023-09.